# React Chart.JS cant move legend (TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I have a Doughnut chart component with this data:

```
  const data = {
    labels: ["1", "2"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "peers",
        data: [1, 2],
        backgroundColor: ["#56E2CF", "#56AEE2"]
      }
    ]
  };
```

The data works right.
These are the options:

```
  const options = {
    legend: {
      display: "right"
    }
  };
```

Component Doughnut:

```
<Doughnut data={data} options={options} />
```

But the chart still has no title:
[image]

---

I have tried to put the options in char.js style, using plugins:

```
  const options = {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: "right"
      }
    }
  };
```

The legend moves but i get a type error (still no title): `The types of 'plugins.legend.position' are incompatible between these types. Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"right" | "left" | "top" | "bottom" | "center" | "chartArea" | _DeepPartialObject<{ [scaleId: string]: number; }> | undefined'`

Notice how the caption has moved to the right:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 const options = {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: "right" as const
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "Title"
      }
    }
  };
```

Here is an explanation from TypeScript docs - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4-rc/#const-assertions

Comment: I would never have guessed it, thanks for the documentation! (For the title i just forgot to import title from chartjs and use it on register)